# mysqli insert execute twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have 2 files, file number is the connection, it look like this

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName= "abc";

// Create connection
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

?>
```

then the second file, where I include the first one, look like this

```
include '../db.php';

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test(a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");


$stmt->bind_param('sssis', $a,$b,$c,$d,$e);

$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

Why does it execute twice when I run the second file? does it cause by the include of the first file?

Comment: From where does `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d`, `$e` come from?; Maybe you refreshed the page?

Answer (score 0):

You must be running the execute twice for sure. It is not visible from this code why it happened twice, page refresh is good candidate.

Add some debugging output to understand what causes this part of code to be run twice.

Comment: You don't answer the question, you just do guess work and that's not the intent of answers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Margus' answer... Is it possible that you are including the second file twice? That would also cause that to happen. You need to be sure that this file is only being run once.